# Coding mobile app with no experience but using porting

Tags: php, android, ios, angularjs, mobile

I've never tried to develop a mobile app before but I've read that there are frameworks for converting web apps (which are coded in AngularJS, PHP, etc.) and turning them into a mobile app. I thought this would be the easiest way to develop one (I'm really not looking for quality, just a quick way to hack something up, I'll later study Objective C and Android Studio, etc.), as I have lots of experience in AngularJS and PHP and web development, but practically zero experience in mobile app development.

I've looked at ionic and PhoneGap and was inquiring on people's experience with them and what approach I should take based on my skillset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you already got some experience with PHP than you should take a look at Zend Studio. It allows developers to use PHP to develop mobile applications. See the following links: [Info](http://venturebeat.com/2012/10/23/huge-news-php-developers-can-now-design-build-and-publish-mobile-apps-right-in-zend-studio/) and here is a [Tutorial](http://files.zend.com/help/Flash-Builder-for-PHP/Getting-Started/Mobile/build_a_mobile_%28php%29_application.htm)